# AsyncTask Returns Error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have been trying to parse XML files using Asynctask, following [[1]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [[2]](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) tutorials. I have implemented a class in my Activity as follows:

```
private class GetRoutes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String[] read;
              try{
                RouteReader route = new RouteReader();
                read = route.getRoutes();
            } catch(IOException iox){
                read = new String[1];
                read[0] = getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error);
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiob){
                read = new String[1];
                read[0] = getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error);
            } catch(NullPointerException npe){
                read = new String[1];
                read[0] = getResources().getString(R.string.loading_error);
            }
          return read;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
          values = result;
        }
      }
```

This is then called in my onCreate method as `new GetRoutes().execute("test");`.
 However, when I try to run this, my app crashes as a result of a NullPointerException ([logcat is available here](http://pastebin.com/m3s8jQrL)).

Could you please guide me on how I can fix this?

---

For further reference, my RouteReader class is as follows:

```
public class RouteReader extends Reader{
public final static String routeURL = 
        "http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeList&a=ttc";
private Map<String, String> routes;

public RouteReader() 
        throws IOException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    super(new URL(routeURL));
    routes = xmlToMap();
}

public String[] getRoutes(){
    return (String[]) routes.keySet().toArray();
}

public String getRouteNum(String route){
    return routes.get(route);
}

private Map<String, String> xmlToMap() 
        throws IOException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String input;
    do{
        input = getReader().readLine();
        if (input.startsWith("<route")){
            String[] read = input.split("\"");
            data.put(read[3], read[1]);
        }
    }while (!input.equals("</body>"));
    return data;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1S"
```

this is probably caused in this line:

```
data.put(read[3], Integer.parseInt(read[1]));
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I missed the "1S". I have edited that class but I still get [an error](http://pastebin.com/y33SVCMV). Could you please guide me on that?

Comment: This error reminds me of situation when you call execute() on reference that is of type AsyncTask, I mean generic types are removed. But if your call is : new GetRoutes().execute("test");, then it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

We'll your log shows a NumberFormatException at RouteReader lines 35. That's not a NullPointerException - it's a failure to parse a string as an integer, because the string is "1S". You should work out what you want to do with invalid data, and handle it appropriately.

Additionally, you're comparing strings with == instead of equals, which is almost never what you want to do. Personally I wouldn't try to use string operations to parse the XML in the first place: use an XML parser... That's what it's there for. Your current approach is very brittle in the face of seemingly-harmless changes in the XML format.

Comment: Ah thanks, I missed the "1S". I have edited that class but I still get an error. Could you please guide me on that?

Comment: Would you recommend that I use DOMparser?

Comment: @mCode: Possibly, or some other XML parser. There are plenty of options available.

Comment: @mCode http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. Quoting docs "We recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android."

Comment: @Raghunandan: Yes, although that's specifically part of a network tutorial. It's not clear that it's *always* the right parser to use. For small files where it's not a problem to have the whole DOM tree in memory, other parsers may lead to simpler code.

Comment: Thank you both, I get started on rewriting that part of my app.